# GWT view shrinks when keyboard popups on android

Tags: gwt, keyboard

I user LayoutPanel in the GWT view and each time i press the TextBox the Keyboard appears and squeezes the view.

on android this happens and on ios it doesnt.

i want to keep the height in proportions to the view original height...

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

A. On resize event in this view, check if user agent is Android. If it is, force the size not to change.

B. Create a different view for Android devices, and then use GWT's deferred binding to substitute your view class if user agent is Android:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred#replacement

This is a another good post:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ConditionalProperties

Comment: how can i force the size not to change?

Comment: The best option is probably to override onResize() for your LayoutPanel, calling super.onResize() for non-Android user agents, and doing nothing otherwise.